# How can I use modulo operator (%) in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, char, character

How can I use modulo operator (%) in calculation of numbers for JavaScript projects?

Answer (score 254, accepted):

It's the **remainder operator** and is used to get the remainder after integer division. Lots of languages have it. For example:

```
10 % 3 // = 1 ; because 3 * 3 gets you 9, and 10 - 9 is 1.
```

Apparently it is not the same as the [modulo operator](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=strawman:modulo_operator) entirely.

Comment: You can fit `3` exactly 3 times in 9. If you would add 3 one more time to 9, you would end up with 12. But you were dividing 10, so instead you say it's 3 times 9 with the remainder being 1. That's what modulo gets you.

Comment: I think it is better to explain it this way: Modulo is the difference left when dividing a value. You can use this to calculate listing lists with items, for example: 10 % 10 gives you 0. When it is 0 you know there a 10 items in a list. For example 20 % 10 gives you the same value, 0, another 10 items in a list......

Comment: There is no "integer division" operator in JS AFAIK; `10 / 3` will result in `3.333...`. You need to truncate the fraction, for instance by using `Math.floor()`.

Comment: @Lucero you're right, I never realised that! I just assumed it used the same basic operator available in many languages.

Comment: @MDeSchaepmeester, well it kind of is using the same basic operator as in other languages, but it lacks a specific integer primitive. JS natively only has "number" primitives which are floating-point, and thus there also are no integer-only operators.

Comment: Why does 1 % x always return 1? Unless x is less than 1?

E.g. 1 % 2 returns 1, why? 1 can't be divided by 2.

Comment: @Paul Redmond, because you can't fit 2 into 1 (= 0 times). This gives the remainder 1.

Comment: Thanks! This helped me answer my coding bootcamp's challenge easily.