# loop popup confusion

Tags: javascript, loops

Can someone tell me how to make my URLs properly loop into the `window.open` I created? I’m wondering if the loop is the right answer to make each URL rotate based on my `setInterval`? If yes, I was wondering if the loop needs to be under `var rotate = []{for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++)};`.

```
var urls = ["http://www.espn.com","http://www.disney.com","http://www.codingforums.com"];
var rotate = 0;
function goRandom()
{
    var newwin = window.open(
        urls[ rotate ],
        "POPUP",
        "height=400,width=600,scrollbars=yes"
    );
}
var loop = setInterval(goRandom, 5000);
```

Comment: you aren't doing anything with `rotate` ... are you getting espn only in your popup window?

Comment: This will give espn on all your tabs, what do you want exactly?

Comment: @JaromandaX yeah it's only giving me espn. I'm try to have all the urls rotates with the setInterval.

Comment: @SaranshKataria i'm just trying to have a SetInterval of those 3 urls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change

```
urls[ rotate ],
```

to

```
urls[ (rotate++) % urls.length ],
```

The index is incremented each iteration and `% urls.length` (% is used for getting the remainder after division, hence it ensures the result never grows beyond the array size). You can [try it here](http://jsfiddle.net/moq3rf62/) (remember to allow popups).

Comment: It is the [modulo operator](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16505559/2948765). It is commonly used in array rotation algorithms to prevent using indices beyond the array size.

Answer (score 0):

You are not updating the value of rotate..

Try doing this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var urls = ["http://www.espn.com","http://www.disney.com","http://www.codingforums.com"];
var rotate = 0;

function goRandom( )
{
    rotate= (rotate+1) % urls.length;
    var newwin = window.open(

                                     urls[ rotate ],
                                     "POPUP",
                                     "height=400,width=600,scrollbars=yes"                          );
}
    var loop= setInterval(goRandom, 5000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

While the other answers are technically correct, here's a simplied version if you're just starting out with js, all that `%` can be confusing.

```
// setup urls
var urls = ["http://www.espn.com","http://www.disney.com","http://www.codingforums.com"];

// rotate is a global variable so can be accessed anywhere
var rotate = 0;

function goRandom( )
{
    var newwin = window.open(
                                     urls[ rotate ],
                                     "POPUP",
                                     "height=400,width=600,scrollbars=yes"                          );

    // move to the next array position
    rotate++;

    // Check if at the end of the array and move back to the beginning
    if (rotate >= urls.length)
        rotate = 0;
}


// Keep going indefinitely
setInterval(goRandom, 5000);
```

Now, your function is called `goRandom()` while this will `goSequence()` (or `goNext()`), so you can change this without any form of loop to pick a random url (though your loop var is called 'rotate' so maybe not what you wanted).

```
// setup urls (global so accessed from anywhere)
var urls = ["http://www.espn.com","http://www.disney.com","http://www.codingforums.com"];

function goRandom( )
{
    // get a random url
    var rotate = Math.floor(Math.random() * (urls.length - 1));

    var newwin = window.open(
                                     urls[ rotate ],
                                     "POPUP",
                                     "height=400,width=600,scrollbars=yes"                          );
}


// Keep going indefinitely
setInterval(goRandom, 5000);
```