# having trouble to understand JavaScript 100%3 and answer comes out 1 in console

Tags: javascript

there,for last few days,i have started learning JavaScript while watching tutorial videos and **`

> the mentor mention something that 100 % 3 answer would be 1 in the
>   console

`** but what i could not get him what he did not describe properly i guess or may be i was to numb to understand.

Can anyone describe properly please whats the issue with 100 % 3 and the answer 1 comes out in the console,so that i could learn JavaScript effective way.

Thank you..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does % do in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900652/what-does-do-in-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use modulo operator (%) in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16505559/how-can-i-use-modulo-operator-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

If you divide 100 by 3, the answer is 33 with a remainder of 1. The `%` character gives you the remainder if you would divide the number on the left by the number on the right.

```
3 % 3 = 0
4 % 3 = 1
5 % 3 = 2
6 % 3 = 0
etc..
```

Comment: Thank You so much..That was quite an answer i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, `%` is a modulus operator. It returns a reminder after a complete integral division of the numerator by denominator.

So `100 % 3 = 1`. `8 % 5 = 3`. `14 % 6 = 2` and so on.