# Call every even column for timestamp script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to create a timestamp for our Google Sheets script. The main goal is to create a script, which would make a timestamp in every "odd" column if something is added to any "even" column.

Right now, I have found this:

```
function onEdit() {
 var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 if( s.getName() == "Sheet1" ) {
   var r = s.getActiveCell();
   if( r.getColumn() == 13 ) { 
     var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
     if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) 
       var time = new Date();
       time = Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT", "HH:mm:ss");
       nextCell.setValue(time);
   };
 };
}
```

It works perfectly, but unfortunately, only for the 13th column. How to make this code work for every even column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the modulo operator (as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16505559/how-can-i-use-modulo-operator-in-javascript)) to check if the edited column is 'even' or 'odd'. Asuming you want the code to work on 'Sheet1', see if this code works for you

```
function onEdit(e) {
if(e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() !== 'Sheet1' || 
e.range.columnStart % 2 > 0) return;
var off = e.range.offset(0, 1);
if(!off.getValue()){ 
off.setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", 
"HH:mm:ss"))
}
}
```