# Anyone know how to check if the index of an array item is even

Tags: javascript

I want to see if the index number of the array item is even, if it is then it should carry out a block of code;

```
var num = 122345643345673;
var convNum = num.toString();
var aftertoString = convNum.split(" ");
function luhnsAlg() {
for (let i = 0; i < aftertoString.length; i++) {
    if (aftertoString[i] == 2) {
        console.log("wow");
    }else{
        console.log("ohh");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean the index, or do you mean the actual digit at that index? It would be unusual to check the index when you could simply guarantee to iterate over the even indices in your for loop with `i += 2` instead of `i++`.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16505559/how-can-i-use-modulo-operator-in-javascript answer your questionß

Comment: for your information the % (modulo) operator will tell you the reminder of a division.. if you divide by 2 and there's no reminder (==0), the number is even otherwise odd.

Comment: Also you need to correctly split the string, it should be `convNum.split("")`. You even don't need to split you can loop over the string as well.

Comment: @jarmod i  mean the index not the digit

Answer (score 1):

You can do :

```
let even = index % 2 == 0;
```

it will return true when even

Comment: Please do not answer questions that have already been answered.

Comment: i'm sorry but i don't agree with that, OP has right to have an answer, even a simple and already answered one, it's impolite to throw a link at him. Most of the questions on stackoverflow have already been answered anyway

Comment: @Lk77 this should be for the digit i want to find out if the index number is even

Comment: That is exactly why you have the "Duplicate" close vote.

Comment: i don't close questions, for me it's offensive

Comment: @SamuelEmeka well it's the same thing, "i" is the "index" in your case, it's the position of the letter within the string

Comment: I changed the "==" sign to "%" and still, nothing happens in the console

Comment: do you execute your luhnsAlg function somewhere ?

Comment: I use code runner

Comment: I just tried calling the function with a button, but the condition is not met

Comment: i have ohh in the console , and for me it's the expected behaviour, since there is only one entry in the array aka : ['122345643345673'], i think you want so split each char in the string, so look at that answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/6484689/8126784, i edited your code : https://pastebin.com/iA1ByWH8

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245103/discussion-between-samuel-emeka-and-lk77).